# What files does an Android database create exactly?

Tags: android, sqlite

In some of my apps I do offer an in-app backup and restore of the Android database. The name of the database file is  set in the SQLiteOpenHelper.

Now I heard that there might be additional files depending on the Android Version and/or the manufactor (e.g. HTC).

What are the names of all these files?

Comment: AFAIK, you've heard wrong. SQLite is SQLite, and the files created shouldn't differ between hardware vendors or Android versions. They may differ somewhat between SQLite versions, but that's not something anyone can provide a list of names for - it would most likely be differences in the internal formats of the files.

Comment: Customers reported up to three files (db/wal/wcs). On my two Android devices its only one file per database always (db). There must be something different between Android releases...

Comment: I have zero file diffs, and none of the `wal`/`wcs` files. What makes you think they're related to SQLite?

Comment: Because they are named "<my chosen databasefilename>-wal" etc.. My question is what additional filenames may exist. It's a fact that they do exist - customers did send screenshots and dir listings from newer Android devices.

Comment: Seems that you didn't get what I'm asking - must be my bad English

Comment: Seems that you didn't get what I'm asking - must be my bad english. Neither the users nor my apps create these files. What I learned in the last hour is that the WAL file is the SQLite WriteAheadLog. This file is new on SQLite 3.7 and becomes part of the database. WAL and DB file build the database. The old traditional DB file can hold only few records while up to 1000 additional commits are stored in the WAL file. A database backup of newer SQLite releases need to include the WAL file. Some Android distributions seem to be configured to work with WAL files.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the question. :-) I'll delete my last comment; can you edit your question to clarify it with what you wrote in your last comment so it's more clear what you're asking? Thanks. :-) Also, your English seems fine to me; I think there just wasn't enough detail in the question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

Standard Android SQLite installations create just one single database file for each database. This file is located in "/data/data//databases" and is named as you instructed to do so for example in the "name" parameter in this constructor:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

So a database file is called for example:

```
/data/data/<packagename>/databases/mydatabase.db
```

SQLite itself has a new feature called Write-Ahead-Logging (WAL). This WAL uses a different logging mechanism than those from traditional database makers. With WAL new commited data will be stored in an additional file that has "-wal" attached to your original filename. For example:

```
/data/data/<packagename>/databases/mydatabase.db-wal
```

This data is missing in the traditional database file until a configurable threadhold is reached - or the app developer instructs the database to move this data over.

However, a WAL-enabled database is not valid with the "*.db" file alone. All additional files are required to form the database. This means a WAL-enabled database will not work on an Android device with an SQLite version that does not support WAL. So a database backup from a WAL-enabled database will not work on older Android systems.

However, only few devices (from HTC for example) and some custom-ROMs enable WAL. Standard Android does not enable WAL.